# Opposing orientation of multi-stage particulate filter in Nitrogen separation/purification system

Tags: compressed-air, compressed-gases, air-quality, air-filtration

I recently purchased an assortment of parts taken out of a Nano Purifications Nitrogen Generator, one of the parts included was a two stage filter for removing particulates from the air stream. The first one was a 5 µm (micrometer) filter, then a 0.01 µm filter, seen below:
[image: Micrometer filter elements from side]

I initially noticed something a little odd, which was that one had an arrow engraved into it to show the air direction, while the other one had a sticker instead (despite both being the same brand). And the mounting threads were on opposite sides:
[image: Micrometer filter elements from top]

However, eventually I noticed the reason behind these little discrepancies. The 2nd stage 0.01 µm filter was actually oriented in the opposite direction than it was manufactured to be, which became apparent when I noticed the indentations on the sticker revealed the underlying arrow pointing in the opposite direction:
[image]

Question: Is there any logic to this? I'm not very experienced with this stuff, but I did look up these types of particulate filters and everything I saw made it very clear that these shouldn't ever be pointed in the direction opposing the airflow going through the filter. But this clearly wasn't some mistake either, so I'm certain there was some logic behind it.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm using it in a nitrogen generator I'm building myself (hence DIY), and if these had some important reason for the odd orientation, then maybe it's something I should include in my project.

Also, I apologize if this isn't the right SE community to post it in, I just wasn't sure which else it would fit in. Let me know if it's not, and I will remove it.